# How to stop Pop_OS 20.10 defaulting to glitchy display settings on boot?

Tags: linux, operating-system, settings, desktop

Just installed pop_OS 20.10. My laptop is connected to a second monitor, I usually have both monitors display the same image.

Every time I boot it changes my display settings to "Join Displays" and then overlaps the two display (I don't know why overlapping the displays is even possible.

[image: Screenshot of my desktop, with settings showing how the displays are overlapping]

I change the display settings to something reasonable but they change back after a restart.

Is there any proper fix for this, or a hacky fix such as changing display settings in a shell script and adding the shell script to startup? (I couldn't find how to change settings through a shell script)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can probably ask on [unix.se] instead, but first you might want to take [their tour](//unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [I realize this question is old; I'm just saying the same thing I would for a new question, and just in case any beginners end up here.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to disable the HiDPI Daemon which is in the Settings -> Display.

[REDDIT thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/i9aq4e/pop_os_never_remembers_my_display_settings/)